# Jetpack Compose ModalBottomSheetLayout onCancel event

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-modalbottomsheetlayout

I'm using `ModalBottomSheetLayout`

```
@Composable
fun BottomSheetWrapper() {
    ModalBottomSheetLayout(
    sheetState = sheetState,
    sheetContent = {
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(1.dp))
        content()
    },
    modifier = modifier,
    content = {}
)}
```

and I want to trigger some logic when user dismisses the `bottomsheet` (back press or touch outside of the `bottomsheet`). In another words I need something similar to `onCancel` event of `BottomSheetDialogFragment`.

What would be the best way to do it with `ModalBottomsheetLayout`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `sheetState` object to observe the state changes of the `ModalBottomSheetLayout` and trigger the required logic when the bottom sheet is dismissed by the user. The `sheetState` object contains an `isExpanded` property that can be used to check whether the bottom sheet is expanded or not.

To listen for the bottom sheet dismissal event, you can add a `DisposableEffect` composable that will execute a callback function when the bottom sheet is dismissed. The `DisposableEffect` composable is used to perform a side effect when a composable is added or removed from the composition.

```
@Composable
fun BottomSheetWrapper(onDismiss: () -> Unit) {
    val sheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(initialValue = ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden)
    
    // Listen for the bottom sheet dismissal event
    DisposableEffect(sheetState) {
        val callback = ModalBottomSheetCallback(onDismiss)
        sheetState.addOnDismissedListener(callback)
        onDispose { sheetState.removeOnDismissedListener(callback) }
    }
    
    ModalBottomSheetLayout(
        sheetState = sheetState,
        sheetContent = {
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(1.dp))
            content()
        },
        modifier = modifier,
        content = {}
    )
}

class ModalBottomSheetCallback(private val onDismiss: () -> Unit) :
    ModalBottomSheetState.BottomSheetStateCallback {
    override fun onStateChanged(bottomSheet: ModalBottomSheetState, newState: ModalBottomSheetValue) {
        if (newState == ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden) {
            onDismiss()
        }
    }
}
```

In this implementation, the `BottomSheetWrapper` composable takes an `onDismiss` lambda as a parameter that will be called when the bottom sheet is dismissed. We use the `DisposableEffect` composable to add and remove a `ModalBottomSheetCallback` that will listen for the bottom sheet dismissal event. When the bottom sheet is dismissed, the `onDismiss` lambda is called.

Comment: This will trigger event every time bottomsheet is hidden. Even when I hide it on successful user interaction. But I need to trigger event only when user clicks outside of the bottomsheet or presses back button.